# Do rolling releases inevitably cause higher fragmentation over time than point releases?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, debian, arch-linux, defragment

Let's compare *Debian Stable* as a candidate for `point releases` and *Arch Linux* as a candidate for `rolling releases`:

**Does a rolling release by default cause higher fragmentation on the drive than a point release?**

Comment: It's not appreciable if you've got enough free disk space and a modern filesystem. You could ask the same question of package systems that build packages locally because of their high file turnover.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, at least not as a rule.

When you install your OS, its always from a fixed point. both scheduled and rolling OSes perform updates which write to files. The only differance comes from the length of time between rebuilds.

Additionally there are other factors that control fragmentation on disk, including the filesystem implementation (and its inherent degree of sparseness) as well as the size of the disk proportional to the amount used.

and then there is the update mechanism. it may unpack whole files, disable the existing version, write the new file in whole, and then delete the prior version. in fact thats more likely than not, so the whole question is likely moot.

Either way, it is impossible to predict degree of fragmentation without knowing the internals of the FS, the update mechanism, the disk, and a number of other factors, so release type is at best a contributing variable.